# control-left and control-right not working in vim, within a screen session

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

In vim, control-left and control-right are back and forward whitespace-separated word (i.e. synonyms for B and W), the same as web textareas and `bash`.

But when running `screen`, these keys stop working. When pressed, vim instead switches to its command line and enters `5C` or `5D` there.

Here is encoding I have for these keys:

```
$ cat >/dev/null    # pressing control-left, then control-right:
^[[1;5C^[[1;5D
```

BTW: I tried remapping these keys in `.screenrc`, like this:

```
bindkey ^[[1;5D stuff B
bindkey ^[[1;5C stuff W
```

This works for vim, but now those keys don't work at the `bash` command line (instead, just outputting `B` or `W`).

I'm guessing this is some `termcap` mysteriousness, which I've never understood... thanks for any enlightenment!

Comment: `$ echo $TERM` changing screen's `$TERM` to `screen-256color` (if it's not already) may help. May I suggest you to get accustomed to `b` and `w`, instead?

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't, I set it with `term screen-256color` in `.screenrc`, and restarting; `echo $TERM` confirmed the change. But it didn't solve the problem. I actually use `b`/`w` all the time - I was very surprised to find myself using `^left`/`^right`. I blame the web.

Comment: Bad bad bad web!

Comment: @romainl :-) it's also the bash commandline - because I'm often switching between bash and vim, that's probably more of a factor than the web. Bad bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to fix this.  One is to note the value of $TERM before you start screen (probably xterm), then after you start vim within screen, set the 'term' option to that value. For example,

```
:set term=xterm
```

Another way is to define mappings for those character sequences:

```
:map <esc>[1;5D <C-Left>
:map <esc>[1;5C <C-Right>
```

You could execute either of those solutions in your ~/.vimrc conditionally on using screen, like this:

```
if &term == "screen"
    map <esc>[1;5D <C-Left>
    map <esc>[1;5C <C-Right>
endif
```

Comment: Brilliant! *Both* work. I found it also works if I set it in .screenrc (`term xterm`), But I guess least disruptive is wisest, so I've used your conditional map answer. BTW the binding is swapped, with 5D for left, 5C for right (the opposite one would expect).  So I used:  `map <esc>[1;5D <C-Left>` and `map <esc>[1;5C <C-Right>`

Answer (score 1):

My `.vimrc` in Ubuntu to handle ctrl arrow keys

```
map  <Esc>[1;5A <C-Up>
map  <Esc>[1;5B <C-Down>
map  <Esc>[1;5D <C-Left>
map  <Esc>[1;5C <C-Right>
cmap <Esc>[1;5A <C-Up>
cmap <Esc>[1;5B <C-Down>
cmap <Esc>[1;5D <C-Left>
cmap <Esc>[1;5C <C-Right>

map  <Esc>[1;2D <S-Left>
map  <Esc>[1;2C <S-Right>
cmap <Esc>[1;2D <S-Left>
cmap <Esc>[1;2C <S-Right>
```